# How do we establish the correspondence between the Krivine machine and classical logic?

Tags: logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus

[In this paper,](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ekrivine/articles/lazymach.pdf) Krivine describes his machine and maps it to classical logic (he implements something like call/cc at the end).

Only, I have trouble understanding how he establishes this correspondence without specifying a type system. Is it purely by talking about input/output rather than type/inhabitant? I saw that the realizability interpretation was about that, but I don't really understand it.